# How to find by an attribute through a join model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I find users who are subscribed to skills which have positions created in the last day?

I wish I could:  User.find(all).where.skills.positions('created_at > ?', Time.now - 1.day)

```
Company      
has_many :positions
has_many :skills, :through => :positions

Position    
belongs_to :company
belongs_to :skill

Skill
has_many :positions
has_many :companies, :through => :positions
has_many :subscriptions
has_many :users, :through => :subscriptions

Subscription
belongs_to :skill
belongs_to :user

User
has_many :subscriptions
has_many :skills, :through => :subscriptions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I've understood your answer completely, but you should be able to do

```
User.all.include({ :skills => :positions }).where(['positions.created_at > ? AND positions.created_at < ?',(Time.now - 1.day).at_beginning_of_day, (Time.now - 1.day).at_end_of_day])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you ! It works. I should learn more about "include({ :skills => :positions }".